# replace certain text if found in div (only working last line)

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, each

```
 let maskElm = '#div-popUp';
 setTimeout(function() {
    $(maskElm).each(function() {
        let text = $(this).html();
        console.log(text);
        
        $(this).html(text.replace('asID', 'DE ID (FFF)'));
        $(this).html(text.replace('LG NAME', 'The Long Name'));
        $(this).html(text.replace('TYPE', 'S12 Type'));
        $(this).html(text.replace('TOWER424', 'Tower')); <-- only line that works as expected, rest ignored, why?
    });
}, 50);
```

Running the above, only the last text is updated (works as expected). Within my `maskElm` popup div, all the above fields exists, and even output consoled in my `console.log(text);` - yet the first 3 text replaces are ignored.. what am I missing here? **Note: I need to do it line by line with `.html` as I do not want to loose formatting..**

***Would I really need to add an `if` check on each text value, additionally? I have about 20 other fields I need to add already. Best route?***

Comment: replace does not alter the original string.... unsure why you would set the html a bunch of times. What do you think is actually happening in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an array of old and new values to make things easier. You can get the HTML content of the element, loop through the values to replace and update the DOM once all of them is replaced:

```js
let maskElm = "#div-popUp";
let toReplace = [
  { "asID": "DE ID (FFF)" },
  { "LG NAME": "The Long Name" },
  { "TYPE": "S12 Type" },
  { "TOWER424": "Tower" }
];

$(maskElm).each(function () {
  let updatedHTML = $(this).html();

  toReplace.forEach((item) => {
    const [oldValue, newValue] = Object.entries(item)[0];
    updatedHTML = updatedHTML.replace(oldValue, newValue);
  });

  $(this).html(updatedHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-popUp">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat aspernatur <b>TYPE</b> eligendi error in consectetur incidunt, <b>asID</b> voluptas autem dolorem deserunt <b>LG NAME</b> praesentium voluptatum eius, rerum magnam laborum id. Porro <b>TOWER424</b> nemo dolore aut.</div>
```

Comment: hopefully the text is only in the string once.

Comment: Hopefully. OP can use `replaceAll()` if the string can occur more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud save variable after .repace

```
let text = $(this).html();
text = text.replace('asID', 'DE ID (FFF)');
text = text.replace('LG NAME', 'The Long Name');
text = text.replace('TYPE', 'S12 Type');
text = text.replace('TOWER424', 'Tower');
```

and then write to element:

```
$(this).html(text);
```